# How to link the same widgets in two activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

in my application have two activity A and B,B activity as a dialog activity.When am in Activity A it show dialog Activity B,i have button in activity B when i click the button,it will refresh the list view in activity A.i don't know how to do this thing.Can any one know please help me to solve this problem.

**Activity A**

```
Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(Activity_A.this, Activity_b.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
```

**Activity b**

```
public class Activity_b extends Activity{

Button yes;




@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_timeout);

    this.rootView=findViewById(R.id.dialog1);
    yes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dialog_yes);


    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            finish();

        }
    });


}



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

        /*Intent i = new Intent(Wheel_order.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();*/
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult` method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities